# JavaScript leaflet map sample will not show

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I am trying to show leaflet on my website and it just will not show, I am following the simple tutorial from http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html and the tiles do not load just get a gray map, this is what I have on my page

```
<head>
 <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" /> 
   <style type="text/css">
    #map {
        height: 180px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    </style>    
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="map">

</div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-key/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>[…]',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
 </script>
 </body>
```

Thats it the map does not show only a gray area has anybody gotten this to work? I am using internet explorer 10 but the map does not show o firefox or chrome either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. You have to take an API key from a tile service.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([36.7667, 13.5833], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/74b831354f3554faa108ac65e3/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
          maxZoom: 18
      }).addTo(map);

      var marker = L.marker([36.752866, 13.556323]).addTo(map);
```

Please notice `74b831354f3554faa108ac65e3`. It's not going to work for you.
You can use this [service](http://account.cloudmade.com/register) to get a API KEY

EDIT 27 APR 2014:
CloudMade is not free anymore. You can use: MapQuest, MapSurfer.NET or openstreetmap.de

Comment: Thank you just did as you suggested and maps are up and running